Where is reputation rankings gone?
Just wondering where the rankings for reputation points are gone. I can't find no link anywhere on the site. Also the message inbox and notification system is probably one of those in need of most overhaul among any comparable site (but this may be an issue hard to fix or update without much effort). Just hinting at the possibility to attract a lot more traffic and interchange with a well functioning private message system, unless you try to avoid non-public communication at all cost. 
At the very least could someone point me to the reputation ranking links, please? Thanks
Btw, was not sure where to post this question, am happy to delete it later if inappropriate here.  

Do you happen to mean the reputation league?  They've changed a little bit since they were introduced, but they're still available if you know where to find them. ;)  I get to them via the "Top Users" tab on StackExchange.com.

thanks, did not know the old one is on the root stackexchange site.

Is this what you wanted? From the main site, click on Users, make sure reputation is selected, and then click on all.

Kind of, before there was a table like ranking, the one I see right now is sorted as well but with tons of user icons all over the screen.
